# Text wrapping around two inline objects, which are in two rows

Tags: html, xhtml

Situation is simple. I need to wrap text around two inline objects (buttons with images), but those buttons should be in two rows (not side by side).

Problem is - necessary buttons are really tiny, (less than half width of the screen) - so they align up in one line.

**Here is what I got now:**

[image]

**And here is what I am trying to achieve:**

[image]

**And here is the code I am experimenting on:**

```
<html>

<body>

<a href="http://link" target="_blank">
<div style="float:right;right:30px;top:30px;display:inline-table;">
<img id="imageTable" width="30" height="30" src="http://www.google.com/intl/lv/services/hp/images/safari-gear.png"/>
</div> </a>

<a href="http://link" target="_blank">
<div style="float:right;right:30px;top:30px;display:inline-table;">
<img id="imageTable" width="30" height="30" src="http://www.google.com/intl/lv/services/hp/images/safari-gear.png"/>
</div> </a>

Nulla facilisi. In vel sem. Morbi id urna in diam dignissim feugiat. Proin molestie tortor eu velit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ultrices, diam tempus vulputate egestas, eros pede varius leo, sed imperdiet lectus est ornare odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin consectetuer velit in dui. Phasellus wisi purus, interdum vitae, rutrum accumsan, viverra in, velit. Sed enim risus, congue non, tristique in, commodo eu, metus. 

</body>

</html>
```

- TableView cannot be used - because then there would be empty space under buttons.
- If I enter a new line between buttons - then text starts wrapping only around second button.
- There is a possibility, that I add a bit text between both buttons, but then I need to calculate precisely how much text should be cut out of main text keeping in mind that font can change etc.

P.S. (for easier helping)
I am testing the code on this site:[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro)

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them both in a `30px` wide `<div>` and float the `<div>` right.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/GdpNv/

Output:

[image]

HTML:

```html
<div id="buttons" style="float:right;width:30px;">
    <a href="http://link" target="_blank">
    <div>
    <img class="imageTable" width="30" height="30" src="http://www.google.com/intl/lv/services/hp/images/safari-gear.png"/>
    </div> </a>

    <a href="http://link" target="_blank">
    <div>
    <img class="imageTable" width="30" height="30" src="http://www.google.com/intl/lv/services/hp/images/safari-gear.png"/>
    </div> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for clear and quick answer! I was wondering - could it be done without css file? (also without <script> in header) ?  I tried putting float: right; width: 30px in <div id="buttons">, but it is not working. Is it possible?

Comment: @GuntisTreulands I just updated the code and demo to not use a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

At the bare minimum here is the code to help with the attempt. Also as a general rule, you shouldn't have multiple elements sharing the same ID.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .imageTable {
        clear: both;
        float: right;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://link" target="_blank" class="imageTable">
<img width="30" height="30" src="http://www.google.com/intl/lv/services/hp/images/safari-gear.png"/>
</a>

<a href="http://link" target="_blank" class="imageTable">
<img width="30" height="30" src="http://www.google.com/intl/lv/services/hp/images/safari-gear.png"/>
</a>

Nulla facilisi. In vel sem. Morbi id urna in diam dignissim feugiat. Proin molestie tortor eu velit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ultrices, diam tempus vulputate egestas, eros pede varius leo, sed imperdiet lectus est ornare odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin consectetuer velit in dui. Phasellus wisi purus, interdum vitae, rutrum accumsan, viverra in, velit. Sed enim risus, congue non, tristique in, commodo eu, metus. 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - nice and clean and helpful (with script part in header.) +1! (but I must accept ThinkingStiff's answer as It provides same answer, but was faster.